# Can Flex/Flash Record the Screen?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, video-capture

This question is pretty straight forward, I literally just want to stream video of a user's computer. Just like recording from a webcam, but with the source coming from the desktop (think "screencasting tool".)  I specifically want to do this in pure Flash, no downloads or add-ons.

This would be an easy question for Google, but it is confused by all of the standalone screencasting tools that "export to Flash", making it impossible to find anything useful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible due to security restrictions. If you check out Adobe's "ConnectNow" product, you'll note that you have to install a special helper application called the "ConnectNow Add-In" in order to use their screen sharing feature. The Add-In is actually an executable file that has the elevated privileges necessary to share / record your screen.

If you're looking for ways to add this kind of functionality to a Flash application, your best bet is to use a signed Java applet with the java.awt.Robot class (which support screen capturing) or a native ActiveX / Browser plug-in. You can then integrate these with Flash using the ExternalInterface / Javascript bridge.

Comment: There is no security reason, using this logic then also webcam and microphone capture should not be possible. Adobe sells some products for this scenario so I assume is a financial decision to not put it in Flash, the workaround we used was to use Java for screen recording and streaming

Answer (score 4):

I sure hope it's not possible.  This would be a huge security flaw.  Imagine visting a rogue web site with a tiny (unnoticeable) swf that streams video of your desktop back to the rogue site.

Comment: It would still have to ask for permission, obviously, in the exact same way as Flash currently asks for permission to record from your webcam/microphone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as the comment above said. Security reasons apart, Flash could not record what's outside the Flash player, let alone the browser.

Don't think it's possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what jdigital said but have noticed on some websites that a popup appears from flash asking if it can have access to a webcam to stream that up, also You tube and the likes let you record from your webcam straight up to the web ( i haven't tried it but presume they use flash for that ), I'm guessing here but if you could substitue the video stream for a vid of the desktop then this should be possible in some way or another.

HTH

OneSHOT

Answer (score 0):

I think to record the computer to screen, you get to download some screen recorder that can export your screen recording as Flash. [**DemoCreator**](http://www.sameshow.com/demo-creator.html#107) is a nice tool to make Flash screencast, and it is with powerful editing features. The free version of **Jing Project** only produces the SWF file, but that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Flex can not record the screen, but if you want to record your flash project which is running in .swf that is possible...
we can record the component of flex, so put your all component inside a component and record that component...

Here's [Check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491649/recording-using-flex-flash)

Answer (score 0):

Flex/Flash can not record the screen due to security sandbox...true.

But it provides a mechanism to record it's component, so this thing we can use.
like....Put all the components inside a Panner (or any other component) and record that component, it can be an alternative to recording the screen.

[Check This](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/1084/1/Screen-capture-with-ActionScript/Page1.html)

and download a swf file from here

[ScreenCapture.swc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Ko8oNP6AZJenowTE9fN0k5Xzg/view)