# How to record the screen application in flex (Fms)?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, video, record, flash-media-server

"Hi!

I have an application with webcam, chat and more, and i need to record the screen aplication in server, for the client not have to upload the result. 
Can some one help me?
Thanks"

What I want is to know how to record the images shown in the Flex application (only inside the swf).

Comment: You do know the client is going to need to upload something... It's impossible to get a screencap from the server without some kind of data transfer between client and server...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Flex/Flash Record the Screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613545/can-flex-flash-record-the-screen)

Comment: i voted to close as this is similar to another related question.  I thought Adobe was going to provide a hosted service to be able to do this; but I can't find any info on it.  ( Neither Cirrus nor LifeCycle Collaboration Service tout this as a feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the same question over at [Can Flex/Flash Record the Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613545/can-flex-flash-record-the-screen), however I disagree with them.   You can render the contents of a movieclip into a bitmap image. The stage is one such object you can render, therefore theoretically you could constantly be rendering these into sequential bitmaps, but you would need some alchemy like encoder to get around the performance hit.

By far the easiest way to go is to record the mouse movements, click actions, or use a insanely well build command pattern to re-recreate the experience elsewhere.

Google as3 command pattern.    Good luck!

Comment: I am sorry, I explained myself badly.
What I want is to know how to record the images shown in the Flex application (only inside the swf).

Therefore, this question is not the same as the one in [Can Flex/Flash Record the Screen? – www.Flextras.com][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613545/can-flex-flash-record-the-screen

Comment: Ah, yeah, render the stage to a bitmap, save the bitmap! var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
bd.draw(stage);
var screenshot:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);

Comment: There is an alchemy lib that generates FLV with bitmapdata. This tutorial explains it better http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/